# HTML date picker doesn't allow to select Years and months on Safari

Tags: html, safari, datepicker, momentjs

In Google date picker allow me to select a year and month without navigating using month to month.

[image: Google date picker]

But in Safari it doesn't allow me to select a year and month directly. Have to navigate month to month. If i need to select a date in two years in advance, then i have to go through 24 months.

[image: Safari date picker]

I have tried using moment jquery library to overcome this issue, but still issue is existing.

`<input type="date" id="inputStartDate" data-date="" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" value="() => moment().toDate()">`

Is there any date picker which we can used in Safari and google both. Date picker should be able to enter the date manually too. Or how can I over come this issue using html date picker.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click in the year and check is it working or not

Comment: Usually it's better to leave your remark - where you want to double check the interaction with the date picker from the one that asked the question - below the question as a comment.
Posting it as Answer might confuse other users that will read your answer later - and won't get a beneficial information out of it. Also, your answer might get downvoted since it's in fact just a comment.

Comment: Chandan that behavior is disable in safarai. Thats why I want to know a possible way to enable or alternative for safari.